# C# Selenium MoveByOffset throwing InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, selenium

I have the following Selenium C# code:

```
IWebElement energyLink= driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Energy"));
Actions clickAction=new Actions(driver);
clickAction.MoveToElement(energyLink).MoveByOffset(-25,0).Click().Build().Perform();
```

On `clickAction.MoveToElement(energyLink).MoveByOffset(-25, 0).Click().Perform();`

I am getting `InvalidOperationException= "Parameter 'x' was not a positive integer(IndexOutOfBounds)"`

My intention is to click on a third party component located at
`X:15 Y:395`

The IWebElement energyLink is located at coordinates `X:40, Y:395`.

Hence I am trying to use `MoveByOffset(-25,0)`

Comment: Isn't the 3rd party component on the page and inside an element? Use it as the reference instead so you can keep the offsets positive.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are executing on Firefox.

After selenium 2.53.1 version it is using geckodriver.exe to execute automation script in Firefox.

> Actions class is not implemented in geckodriver. So you are getting
>   that error.
>
> If you execute in chrome, then you won't get that exception.

If you want to execute in Firefox then you have to use older version of selenium which don't need geckodriver

Answer (score 0):

ClickAndHOld : It is used for left Click the particular element and hold
MoveByOffset:  Move that holding element into a given position
Release : release the element at current offset position
build and perform : to Complete the action.

```
    IWebElement energyLink= driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Energy"));
    Actions clickAction=new Actions(driver);
    clickAction.ClickAndHold(energyLink).MoveByOffset(-25,0).Release().Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Hi Amit, Welcome to Stackoverflow, thanks for sharing your solution, I'll just recommend you to describe more how does that solution works, what have you done different and why the original code would not work, if possible